# how to stop http urls from indexing?

Tags: .htaccess, google-index

I want to block http urls from indexing ,I want https urls only be indexed by googlebots,

I have tried this code in htaccess file but its not working[blocking

```
#blocking http urls from indexing
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
RewriteRule ^robots.txt$ robots-deny-all.txt [L]
```

I wrote this code inside robots-deny-all.txt

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

appreciate your help

Comment: Please edit your question (there is an edit button below it): replace those links to images by the actual code you include in the question. There are reasons why the rules on this place explicitly requests that for all questions. Thanks.

Comment: i tried i dont know why it becomes links i used image little icon to upload screenshots

Comment: As said: code is code, a screenshot is something else. Screenshots are offered to allow for optical impressions, for example for stylesheet stuff.

Answer (score 0):

only you have to wait for one week to see result , the code works well

in case you wanted to block https replace 80 by 443

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).